# Efficient looping in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, loops

I'm using [Parse](https://parse.com/) as my backend service, but for this example I created two sample Arrays (`songs` and `ratings`) that mimic my backend schema. `songs` consists of song data that will populate my app's table. `ratings` consist of the current user's ratings of songs.

Ultimately, I need to loop through `songs` and `ratings` to embed the `userRating` in the respective `songs` dictionary. I've included my looping code below. Can this be done more efficiently? I'm worried it will take too long if there are too many `ratings` objects.

```
    NSMutableArray *songs = [@[ @{
                                @"objectId" : @"111",
                                @"title" : @"Song Title" },
                                @{
                                @"objectId" : @"222",
                                @"title" : @"Song Title"
                             } ] mutableCopy];

    NSMutableArray *ratings = [@[ @{
                               @"objectId" : @"999",
                               @"parentObjectId" : @"111",
                               @"userRating" : @4
                               } ] mutableCopy];

    for (NSInteger a = 0; a < songs.count; a++) {

        NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [songs objectAtIndex:a];
        NSString *songObjectId = [songInfo objectForKey:@"objectId"];
        NSNumber *userRating = @0;

        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < ratings.count; i++) {

            NSDictionary *userRatingInfo = [ratings objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *parentObjectId = [userRatingInfo objectForKey:@"parentObjectId"];

            if ([parentObjectId isEqualToString:songObjectId]) {
                userRating = [userRatingInfo objectForKey:@"userRating"];
            }
        }
    [songInfo setObject:userRating forKey:@"userRating"];
    }
```

Comment: wow - what do @[ and @{ do? unfortunately I can't work out how to google them!  Are they static array and dictionary constructors?

Comment: they are shortcut syntax to invoke `[ NSArray arrayWithObjects:... ]` and `[ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:... ]`. Not static, though.

Comment: where's the documentation on them?

Comment: I believe here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: They're new syntax since (IIRC) Xcode 4.4. You must use the modern runtime (i.e. anything but 32-bit Mac OS X.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a dictionary of ratings instead of having an inner loop. Your time complexity will go from n*m to n+m since dictionary lookups are amortized constant time:

```objc
NSMutableDictionary* ratingsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:ratings.count];
for (NSDictionary* rating in ratings) {
    NSString *parentObjectId = [rating objectForKey:@"parentObjectId"];
    [ratingsDict setObject:rating forKey:parentObjectId];
}

for (NSMutableDictionary* song in songs) {
    NSString *songObjectId = [song objectForKey:@"objectId"];
    NSNumber *userRating = [ratingsDict objectForKey:songObjectId];
    if (userRating)
        [song setObject:userRating forKey:@"userRating"];
}
```