# Data Model Design

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, data-modeling

I'm a bit stuck designing the data model for my iOS app. I'm using [Parse](https://parse.com/) as my backend service which has two data classes: `Songs` and `Ratings`(user ratings). When my app launches, I'm currently making 5 separate queries to Parse that make up 5 possible data sources for my UITableView:

1. mainQuery - daily uploaded songs
2. topTracksOfTheWeek - top rated songs of the week
3. topTracksOfTheMonth
4. topTracksAllTime
5. userRatedTracks - songs the user rated

Parse makes it easy to add constraints to the query to return the desired data. However, I also need to compare `userRatedTracks` to each of the other queries and embed the `userRating` into each datasource if it exists for each track. (which I learned how to do effectively here: [Efficient looping in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397483/efficient-looping-in-objective-c)

I'm having trouble figuring out how optimize or change this design for better performance. All of the above queries are called in a method `getDataSource` which is called in `viewDidLoad` and then a method `assignDataSource` sets the table's data source array depending on which data source the user has selected (`mainQuery` being the default). Ideally, on app launch `mainQuery` is fetched on the main thread, populates the table, and the other queries are fetched in a background thread. However, this would be inefficient if the user selects to view the `topTracksOfTheWeek`. When `getDataSource` is called and `topTracksOfTheWeek` query doesn't have priority.

The easy way to go would be to lazily load each query as I need them, but I'm worried this will hinder the responsiveness of the app compared to loading all the data initially.

As you can probably tell, I'm a beginner. I find design patterns to be extremely frustrating as a beginner because I always think there is a better way to structure code than the way I'm doing it. Does anyone have any advice on design with multiple data sources?

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the results into Core Data? You could load/sync the data in a background MOC and save to core data. When a user launches it pulls the local results until the new parse results are refreshed and show an indicator so the user knows the data is being refreshed. Check out Ray Wenderlichs tutorial, its almost EXACTLY what you need to perform this. Even uses Parse

http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1